# Specify different actions for different values of a variable in an if-else block

Tags: java, if-statement

I am a beginner to Java (I learnt C before this) and this seems to be a simple question but I'm stuck here. What if I want some action to be taken for different values of a variable??

for example-

```
if(r==1)

else if(r==2)
   //take action2
else if(r==3)
  //take action3
  .
  .
  .
```

and so on.

How to generalize this for any value of 'r' (assume value of r can range from 1 to any number, which is determined in run time) ?

I am passing the value of 'r' as a parameter to the function containing the above code block.

EDIT: Let me explain the problem more clearly.

Now imagine I have a list like this:

```
   Items: a b c d

T1:       1 1 0 1
T2:       0 1 0 0
T3:       1 1 0 0
T4:       0 0 1 1
T5:       1 0 1 1
```

(Here '1' means: there is an occurrence of that item in T1 or T2 or T3 or T4 or T5.
'0' means: there is no occurrences)

now for r=1: I have to count the number of occurrences a's, b's, c's, d's individually in T1,T2,T3,T4,T5.

for r=2: I have to count the number of occurrences of (a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,c) and (c,d) in T1,T2,T3,T4,T5.

for r=3: I have to count the number of occurrences of (a,b,c), (a,c,d) ... and so on.

I hope you get the idea.

I have already written the code for the permutations above and am planning to pass that as a list and 'r' as parameters.

(For those who know data mining, you might have already guessed that I am trying to implement one of the algorithms!)

Comment: Are there as many actions as there are possible values of `r`?

Comment: `switch`  to `switch` :)

Comment: @Sotirios..Almost, yes. Basically the action taken here is counting 'r' number of integers in a list. So if (r==1), count the number of single integers (1;2;etc). if (r==2), count the number of 2-integer combinations (1,2; 1,3; etc) and so on

Comment: @Suresh.. switch case cannot be used for ANY value of 'r' right..?

Comment: @user2740354 You'll need to convert that into a generic mathematical formula and make that the body of your method, taking `r` as an argument when it's called.

Comment: Looks like you could build a regular expression based on the value of r. (xkcd #208 anyone?)

Comment: Wait, just to check that I've understood this properly. You start with a list, say `1, 2, 3, 4`, then want to see how many combinations of `r` numbers you can make from it? So if r == 1, you can make four combinations. If r == 2, you can make 12 combinations. If I *have* understood that correctly, that's just basic statistics (permutations); I'd be surprised if there wasn't already a Java library to do that for you. If not, the formula is pretty basic: `l! / (l - r)!` where `l` is the number of integers in your list.

Comment: @Anthony..I'm sorry, I guessed that the comment was very abstract so I made the needed edits in the question. I have already made the permutations using recursive functions

Comment: How is this data held? in a 2D array?

Comment: It is held in an Arraylist.. Each time the function is called, the Arraylist first contains just the individual elements, later the 2-combinations, then the 3-combinations, and so on

Comment: Yes, but inside the arraylist, you have a table in your question, tell me how that table is represented in your code (or even better show the code for the table).

Comment: Or what `//take action2` represents

Comment: @Richard.. The table is actually an input file. The ArrayList has the items (a, b, c, d). When I first implemented it, I did not think ahead and just counted individual item occurrences (not even thinking about the combinations) and stored the count of each item in the Arraylist along with the corresponding item. I realize my mistake now. I just want to count the occurrences of these items in each T so that I can base my further calculations on this.

Comment: @Richard..I'm so sorry I didn't mention this before, I read the file initially and store it in a 2D array!! so action2 is like:

if( trans [a] [T1] && trans [b] [T1] == 1) count++;

of course the above code comes in 2 for loops

Comment: There we go then, if you have the 2D array then all you need do is count up the "1"s on a single line. FYI putting ... after a name when using @user breaks it

Comment: @RichardTingle  I have already done that..for r = 1. My point was, how to generalize it for any 'r' ?? in action2, i have used just a single '&&'.  for action3, i have to use two '&&'.. it will go on and on :(

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that the table quoted in your question is represented internally as a 2D array, as such counting up how many items `Tx` have `r` combinations is as simple as counting up how many rows have `r` number of "1"s in them.

```
   Items: a b c d

T1:       1 1 0 1
T2:       0 1 0 0
T3:       1 1 0 0
T4:       0 0 1 1
T5:       1 0 1 1
```

Represented as;

```
int[][] data=new int[noOfT][noOfLetters];
```

Then use as;

```
   public static int count(int[][] arrayToCount, int noOfCombinations){

       int count=0;
       for(int i=0;i<arrayToCount.length;i++){
           int thisRowCount=0; //how many items are on this row

           for(int j=0;j<arrayToCount[i].length;j++){
               if (arrayToCount[i][j]==1){
                   thisRowCount++;
               }
           }


           if (thisRowCount<=noOfCombinations){ //if this row has the a sufficient number of items increase the count
               count++;
           }
       }

       return count;
   }
```

Comment: Wow it works!! :) but the problem is, for 2-combinations in T4 and T5 which has 0 0 1 1 and 1 0 1 1. (c,d) occurs twice in these two T's, but it doesn't count the (c,d) in T5.... I guess this is because, thisRowCount != noOfCombinations in the 2nd case)

Comment: @user2740354 Would T5 not be a 3 combination?

Comment: Or is T5 a 1,2, and 3 combination? In which case we just need to adjust the == to <=

Comment: Yup T5 is only a or b or c or d when noOfCombinations  = 1..when noOfCombinations  = 2, it is (a,b), (a,c), (b,c), (b,d), (c,d). when noOfCombinations  = 3, it is (a,b,c), (a,c,d), (a,b,d) and (b,c,d). 
If we adjust <= then it will accept all the combinations <= noOfCombinations  right.. for one call of the function, it should accept only for noOfCombinations ..

Comment: @user2740354 Ok, just so i'm clear, r=1 should be `T1,T2,T3,T4,T5=5` r=2 is `T1,T3,T4,T5=4` r=3 is `T1,T5=2`?

Comment: Well..we consider for all transactions.

 for r = 1 : occurrence of a =3, b=3,c=2, d=3. for r = 2: occurrence of (a,b) = 2, (a,c) = 1,  (a,d)=2,  (b,c)=0,  (b,d)=1 and that of (c,d)=2. for r = 3: occurrence of (a,b,c)=0, (a,c,d)=1, (a,b,d)=1 and (b,c,d)=0.

Comment: Yup..just counting occurrences of all the combinations :) But I understood your code, I think by some modifications, I can get it right :) Thank you so so much :)